# Can I have notify icon for my external program called by shell?

Tags: vb.net, exe, notifyicon, multiple-projects

I'm developing one exe program (A) that have link to call another exe(B). But then, I have an issue to set up notify icon for exe (B).

Here codes to call exe(B):

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked

    Shell("C:\\programB.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)

End Sub
```

How do I put the notify icon to exe(B)?

Answer (score 0):

You could not modify the application at the runtime.. but, you can hold the process of Application B and then you can display the notify icon in the task bar until the application is running.

```
Dim bHasNotifyIcon As Boolean = False
Dim process As Diagnostics.Process = Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\ProgrammB.exe")

If Not process.HasExited Then 
    bHasNotifyIcon = True
    'Show Notify Icon
End If

Do While (Not process.HasExited)
    'Do nothing
Loop

'Hide Notify icon if application is running
If bHasNotifyIcon Then 
    'Hide Notify Icon
End If
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to run above code in different thread otherwise it will hang the application. and possible it can give error while you are trying to access UI from different thread.

Yes, i know this is the dirtiest method. but, i don't know any other method.